# How to program MX Revolution buttons on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: mouse

I found my old Logitech MX Revolution mouse. I want to edit the buttons in Ubuntu. I'm looking for a software that can help me do that. I have already tried Solaar and Piper, but they don't detect my mouse. The mouse works fine with the computer, but I'd like to customize what the additional buttons on it do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can only program the mouse with Windows or Mac. The Logitech MX Revolution uses a software called Setpoint. The mouse is still usable

Comment: There seem to be solutions. A quick google search brings up [this source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Logitech_MX_Revolution) as the first hit, describing exactly what you're looking for. The 3rd hit is an open-source code on Github, [revoco](https://github.com/sebastien/revoco), specifically for this. Did you try these, and if yes, why did they not work?

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into that. While I was researching for this a year ago, I could not find revoco.